# test with httpcode in php

Tags: php

I use this code in my application php

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false); // remove body 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$data = curl_exec($ch);  
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch); 

if ( $httpCode == 500 ) {
  $result["status"] = 0;
  $result["go"] = 0;
  $result["message"] = "Une erreur s'est produite ";
  echo $_REQUEST["callback"] . "(" . json_encode($result) . ");" ;
  exit;
}

$data   = json_decode($data, true);
$result = array();

$result["status"]  = -1;
$result["go"]      = -1;
$result["message"] = "";
```

and when I execute my application I have this message :

> Une erreur s'est produite

I want to know in which case httpCode is equal 500

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, `$url` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I'm understanding your question, but if you're looking for a definition of the various HTTP Status Codes, see [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

As quoted by W3 for a `500` error:

> The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

This means that there's a problem on the server that you're requesting. Often this can be attributed to a badly configured web-server, or an error in the server's `.htaccess`.